# Mercurial, configuring a server to allow anyone to push to it

Tags: mercurial

Im working through the following tutorial [Mercurial Turotial](http://hginit.com/02.html) and im stuck with the following:

> Now I’m going to use the hg push command, which will push my changes from my repository into the central repository:
>
> C:\Users\joel\recipes> hg push
>   pushing to http://joel.example.com:8000/
>   searching for changes
>   ssl required
>   Oh great. It figures that wouldn’t work. I neglected to think about the security implications of just running a random web server and allowing anybody in the world to push their stupid changes into it. Bear with me for a moment; I’m going to configure that server to allow anybody in the world to do anything they want to it. This can be done by editing the file .hg\hgrc on the server:
>
> .hg\hgrc
>   [web]
>   push_ssl=False
>   allow_push=*
>
> Needless to say, this is rather unsafe, but if you’re on a nice protected LAN at work and there’s a good firewall and you trust everybody on your LAN, this is reasonably OK. Otherwise, you’ll want to read the advanced chapters on security.

which file is he accessing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't create configuration files automatically.
If you need the file and it doesn't exist, just create it yourself and put the settings from the tutorial inside.

Quote from [Configuration files for Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html):

> **Files**
>
> Mercurial reads configuration data from several files, if they exist.
>   These files do not exist by default and you will have to create the
>   appropriate configuration files yourself